# Custom folder field for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, directory, explorer

I would like to be able to add a custom field to folders in windows 7, and then be able to show that column(field) when viewing the folder in explorer (sort and group etc).

**Question:**

How can I achieve this? (is there a program I can buy / use or is there a way of doing this in windows 7?)

Example use case: I have folders for each job that I do - I'd like to mark the folder as "pending", "done" etc. I'm using custom folder markers at the moment - but that's limited. Having a number of these fields would be really powerful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need to create a new Windows Property. See *Windows Property System* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728898(VS.85).aspx. I do not know of any program that allows you to create properties.

Moreover, see *Creating Custom Properties* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144135(VS.85).aspx.

Here is an MSDN search for "Windows Property System" to get you started (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=%22Windows%20Property%20System%22)

Note, that Windows Runtime (WinRT) will make handling this properties fairly easy.

Comment: Do you know what type of developer I am looking  for if I need to create a custom application to add these properties ?

Comment: A Windows Shell programmer. I been meaning to create a couple of properties for source code files, but never can find the time.

Comment: I know TortoiseSVN adds custom properties, you could use that as a start. If I ever get bored I might look at this as it seems a fun and useful project. My first try would be to store the values of custom properties in the NTFS alternate data stream so they get moved/copied with the files as well.

Answer (score 0):

> See: http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2008/06/how-to-set-custom-attributes-file.html

It appears using the `DSOFile` DLL from Microsoft you can add custom attributes to a file as long as it is on a NTFS.
However re-saving some file types depending on how their applications handle it - may strip the previously added custom property.

Answer (score -3):

I think, you are just being silly, this will quickly overwhelm you with information overload,

you should simply instead of adding columns, just create folders and dump every folder you need inside it like so,,,

```
> - Pending
>    - client 1 
>    - client 2
> - Done 
>    - client 3
```

lets, say you have finished with client 2 you just drag and drop it on the Done folder, or cut, and paste it on done,

easier to manage,

here is a something, I stumbled across, I think its alot more difficult to manage eitherway, your better off using excel, or simply the structure I mentioned above.

http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2005/12/10/msh-get-extended-properties-of-a-file/

hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Silly? Lol. What kind of answer is that?

Comment: the MSH does answer the question, its a method of adding properties, so don't know where you get that from @AMissico

Comment: @val That's for files NOT folders.

Comment: I think this is out-of-the-box thinking that deserves a point.  Val has pointed out that it might be easier to add a custom folder with some files inside the folder that should hold the properties.  This is akin to the .svn folders that hold private information for any folders that are part of the SVN working directory.